# Related to Cassandra Data modeling

Tags: cassandra, nosql, data-modeling, datastax-enterprise

Requirement: Table is in Cassandra. We need section numbers for jobs which never completed successfully from following table:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id UUID, section text, result text, PRIMARY KEY(job_id,section));

INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0100','successful');
INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0100','successful');

INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0200','successful');
INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0200','failed');

INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0300','failed');
INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0300','successful');

INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0400','failed');
INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0400','failed');

INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0700','failed');
INSERT INTO  SAMPLE.ALERTS (job_id, section, result) values (now(),'0700','failed');
```

So in output we want section number 0400 and 0700. Is there anyway by which we can achieve it by changing structure of table and through query?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, such kind of stuff is done by adding materialized views, or secondary indices, but in your case this is not optimal as you don't have many different `result` values...

If you're using DSE, then you can use DSE Search to perform such queries (but take into account that latency for such queries will be higher than normal Cassandra queries).

Another possibility - just add 2nd table, where you'll write only failed requests (as copy of original data).